# Why does Listview scrolling refresh my results?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I'm using a `ListView` with a custom adapter. On press of a row I am updating the item in the list. But every time I'm scrolling up or down it refills the items in the `ListView` and changes back to the default value.

This is my class:

```
class CategoryPreviewClass
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryID { get; set; }
}
```

This is the adapter:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.CategoryPreview, null, false);

        }


        TextView txtCategoryName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCategoryName);
        txtCategoryName.Text = mitems[position].CategoryName;
        TextView txtCategoryID = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCategoryID);
        txtCategoryID.Text = mitems[position].CategoryID;

        txtCategoryName.Click += delegate
        {
            txtCategoryName.Text="CustomText";
        };


        return row;
    }
```

Should I save the changed values on every press of the `ListView`?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYHJd.jpg)

Comment: Define "changes". What actually happens?

Comment: I'm changing txtCategoryName text when i'm pressing on row. But if i will scroll down and then up again it changes to default value, just like listview show for first time. Its a very common listview issue as i read in forums but i dont know what should i do for keeping the changes inside my adapter.Or if there is any way which i can change item inside row text with listview itemclick event

Comment: I would say it happens because you don't attach the listview item anywhere in layout. Inflater isn't given any root, and you even forbidden it to attach the view to the root.

Comment: If you need farther code info just let me know.Should i create a bool statement which i will override only rows which value is false?

Comment: try moving all your the stuff you do to initialize the view inside the `if (row==null) {}` block and see what happens. Reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/populating) suggests that method can be called with an existing view, in which case its text will be overridden. What do you actually want to do with that click update? Why do you update view instead of updating the actual item data if you want it to be preserved?

Comment: @ M. Prokhorov it didint worked

Comment: then we need to work out what can we do to go around limitations in a list view. What purpose do these changes hold? Can you save them into a `CategoryPreview`?

Comment: I updated my post with a picture above, item with blue background color indicates the  selected items.  I need keep this items   selected (blue color) even if my listview will scrolling down or up.I already tried ViewHolder but it didnt worked neither. I can post this approch too if you need so

Comment: Should i use NotifyDataSetChanged Method if something like row color is changed inside my adapter?

Comment: Any Suggestion?

Comment: What it looks like to me is actually you just need to have a list selection mode which allows multiselect. [See here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Widget.ListView.ChoiceMode/). You need `ChoiceMode.Multiple` and to customize how a selected item would look.

Comment: And here is [one possible way](https://blog.wislon.io/posts/2017/04/11/xamforms-listview-selected-colour) you can go to configure how a selected list item is styled. Quite frankly, me being not a Xamarin developer, I'm amazed at how many useful features is missing in that platform. (Sure, they let you customize a bunch, but the amount of that warrants a full-fledged wrapper library for all base components).

Comment: I think i understood which the problem is. My listview is populated from sql server. SqlServer Saves value to my class CategoryPreviewClass. So every time i'm scrolling listview is reading from my class. Correct me if i'm wrong. So if i will change a value not static in listview but in my class then it will show it right when i'm scrolling. The thing is how should i change a specific item in my class from my adapter

Comment: I don't think that's what it is. But you can check that if you intercept the reader and log read operation somewhere. Some of your problem indeed comes from you changing only view and not dataset, but looking just at this code I can't tell what you can/should do.

Comment: Do you need more code to for showing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a holder for your adapter so that your items are not recreated every time you scroll.

```
private class Holder {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
}
```

And then in your getView method you have to call these textviews by holder name.

For more information refer to this link:

https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/19/android-listview-with-viewholder-tutorial/#.WsumLojwZPY

Comment: They aren't recreated, and having this holder with predefined number of elements defeats the whole point of even having a `List`.

Comment: No it doesnt defeats the point of having list. Infact if you are not using holder your adapter items are going to be recreated which is a bad approach. This is called HOLDER PATTERN for list items. You should give it a try first !

Comment: If you use holder pattern your issue will be resolved !

Comment: The link you attached instructs to use holders because they think searching for a view is expensive. They say nothing about items being recreated. And, in fact, there is nothing wrong with views being recreated if system needs to do it. View is a **view**, it should not hold any data that needs persistence, and all cases for it being created and destroyed correspond with system notifying your code about that, so you can make necessary adjustments.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov So according to you Recycler View is a waste of time as it uses a holder patter as well ?? And this link is for helping purpose not the exact same answer to the question.

Comment: There is a difference between using recycler views and rolling your own clunky implementation that sets holders inside view tags, isn't there? RecyclerView is implemented this way specifically because it manages holders and not views. As for the link, when I look at this answer, I only see a link and pretty much nothing else apart statement that blindly following this pattern (stated to be used for completely another reason in the same resource which was recommended) magically fixes all problems.

Comment: Well then stop looking at the answer and do your stuff . I don't think you are gonna understand my point :)

Comment: Exactly. I *don't* understand your point. And since you are trying to answer a question, I feel like it's on you to make your point clearer. So, what is the point of holding onto views from the component which might delete them to free the memory as part of its (well tested and verified) workflow? How does that address the problem at hand? Where do you suggest storing these holders in meantime, and what do you suggest to implement in terms of management of these views when they are removed from parent view?

Answer (score 0):

> But every time I'm scrolling up or down it refills the items in the ListView and changes back to the default value.

Because of you only change the text in the textview, not the data in `mitems`. When the listrow is recycled and rebind, it bind data from `mitems` again. So you need to modified the data in `mitems`.
For example:

```
    txtCategoryName.Click += delegate
    {
        txtCategoryName.Text = "CustomText";
        mitems[position].CategoryName = "CustomText";
    };
```